# Definir dimension de Array por JOptionPane

Tags: java, array

esta es mi primer consulta, estoy aprendiendo Java y me tope con este obstaculo, quiero hacer un array que lo defina el usuario, es decir, que no este previamente seteada la dimension desde el codigo, sino que se modifique desde JOptionPane. Aca muestro un ejemplo de lo que intente.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        String dimensionArray=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("definir tamaño de array");


        String[] array=new String[dimensionArray];
```

Bueno, claramente no me deja hacerlo, ya que en el lugar donde se coloca el tamaño del array me pide un int y yo estoy poniendo un string.
¿se puede hacer esto que estoy intentando?

Desde ya, muchas gracias!

Comment: [Aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3120922/joptionpane-input-to-int) hay una pregunta similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para poder que puedas hacer eso deberas de tener es un int,  en vez de un string,  para ello deberas intentar parsear el numero que digito el usuario,  me explico,  tu tienes esto:

```
String dimensionArray=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("definir tamaño de array");
```

Y lo que deberias tener es esto:

```
int dimensionArray = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("definir tamaño de array"));
```

Solo con esos cambios ya deberias poder usar dimensionArray como tamaño de tu otro array.

Comment: Genial Riven, me ayudo tu respuesta, muchas gracias!